# C++ STL Vector of lists inserting elements at the end of the lists

Tags: c++, list, parsing, vector, stl

I got a series of numbers and I need to make a vector of lists `std::vector<std::list<int>> v`. I will give an example because it's easier to explain. Example:

Series of numbers: `5 7 2 0 3 9 10 4`

Vector after parsing the numbers: `v[0] = {5, 0}; v[1] = {2, 10, 4}; v[2] = {7, 3}; v[3] = {9}`
And `{2, 10, 4}` is a list.

I want to parse the series of numbers once and put the numbers directly in the vector at the end of the list. For this example, put 5 in `v[0]`, then put 7 in `v[2]`, then put 2 in `v[1]`, then put 0 at the end of the list in `v[0]` after 5...

Comment: You forgot to tell us the most important thing: How to know which number goes where, and why it does that.

Comment: That doesn't matter that much, I want to know only how to insert an element in a vector on a specific position at the end of the list that is on that specific position. I mean how can I insert let's say the number 1000 in v[0] after 5 and 0

Comment: `vector_name[index].push_back(value)`?

Comment: You do it exactly the same as you do for standalone list - calling `push_back()` or `emplace_back()` or in your case `v[0].push_back( 5 );` etc. You need to initialize the vector properly - to have at least 4 elements in it.

Comment: Ah I see, all I could find on google was making a list first with the elements and than inserting the list in the vector, thanks a lot NathanOliver (should have posted as answer) and Slava.Edit: Slava I know the number of elements at the vector at the start of program so it's all good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to know only how to insert an element in a vector on a specific position at the end of the list that is on that specific position.

to append `val` to the list at position `i`, you would:

```
v[i].push_back(val);
```